# W7 repeatedly wants to install SP1

Tags: windows-7, installation

I successfully installed SP1 for Windows 7. Several weeks afterwards my update package wanted to re-install SP1. Now, almost every day it wants to reinstall SP1. Also, I have been unable to install Security update KB2667402. My machine is devoting considerable time repeatedly downloading and trying to install these packages. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows Update component seems to be corrupted, you need to fix it.

Windows 7 already includes a built-in troubleshooting platform that can be accessed from the Control Panel. It contains several troubleshooting programs (packs) that can automatically fix some common problems with your computer, such as problems with Windows Update.

You can access Troubleshooting by clicking ...

Control Panel (in Category view) > under System and Security > Find and fix problems > Fix problems with Windows Update

or, Control Panel (in Icon view) > Action Center > Troubleshooting > Fix problems with Windows Update

If your PC does not have this pack installed, you can run or download it from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/).

Comment: `sfc /scannow` is a very helpful tool.

Comment: @Ramhound I had the same problem, but with a different update. It was [repeatedly installing the same update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339) on every reboot as Windows Update was unable to detect it. Windows Update database was corrupted and I had to reset it.

Comment: I was just suggestion another tool that might help.  Your answer is fine.

Comment: I tried fixing the problem through the Control Panel. It said it had fixed it, but still would not install. I tried downloading from your response. Still no success. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821). If this still doesn't fix the issue, zip and upload the folder C:\Windows\Logs\CBS.